# Pip не устанавливает пакеты

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Думаю, проблема началась после того, как я хотел обновить pip в виртуальном окружении, но по незнанию использовал sudo и обновил pip глобально. Теперь у меня не ставятся пакеты через pip совсем. Можно ли это как-то исправить? Или меня спасет только переустановка системы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете попробовать `python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip`

Comment: Кажется, помогло. Большой спасибо!